# Use Javascript Cookies to Track HP in an HTML5-Based Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I am working on a website, which is essentially a linear choose-your-own-adventure game (Scene 1 goes to Scene 2 no matter what choice you choose). However, each choice you make will cause a change in health, if the health hits 0 you lose. At this point, I am supposed to create this using mainly HTML5 & CSS3 with some JavaScript integration.

I built the game so that there are links from one page to the next page, I am just not sure how to track the hp. My instructor suggested that we look into cookies, but I have not been able to get the cookies to be made (Problem 1). Even if I were able to get the cookies to work, I don't know how I would change the destination of the link if they hit 0hp, so that the game ended, and the final message is displayed.

If it helps here is the HTML

---

The three options

```
<ul id="horizontal-list">
    <li><a
        href="S3B.html"
        class="ghost-button">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a
        href="S3C.html"
        class="ghost-button">Option 2</a></li>
    <li class="third"><a
        href="S3A.html"
        class="ghost-button">Option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Then on the next page

```
<ul>
    <li><a
        href="../S4/S4.html"
        class="ghost-button">Go on to the next scene</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need it to check the value of the players HP after they click the "Go on to the next scene" button, and if they have a HP of 0, they go to a different page, but if they have an HP greater than 0, they go to the file at

> ../S4/S4.html

I have a very basic knowledge of js syntax, but am an experienced programmer in general and understand most of the concepts involved in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method you could do this would be to store their health as a variable in the browser's local store:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("HP", "100");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

and if you'd like to manipulate that value, you would simply change it just like you would do with an object property:

```
localStorage.HP = parseInt(localStorage.HP) - hitpointsLost;
```

(localStorage variables are stored as strings, so we have to use parseInt to treat it like an integer and remove some HP)

You can then destroy the data sample when they lose by doing:

```
localStorage.removeItem("HP");
```

Whenever you're remove the HP, have some function or check to see if the user's HP has hit 0 or less, and then use `window.location.assign('newlocation.html')` to redirect them to the "You Lost" page.

Comment: Ok, so once i have the score variable, how do I end the game when they lose? My thought process is that I change the destination of the link to a 'You Lose' page, but I don't know how to do that since HTML does not have a conditional statement that I am aware of.

Comment: I just added that at the end of my answer. Sorry, forgot to put that in the first time.